# If dual of quasi-isomorphism quasi-isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $L,M$ be complex of finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}$ modules, $f\colon L\to M$ is a quasi-isomorphism, $g\colon M^\vee\to L^\vee$ is a quasi-isomorphism. Is it still true for $\mathbb{Z}/n$ modules?

The motivation for this question is this: given a smooth manifold, we can find a finite good cover, and use its Cech complex to compute the cohomology of the manifold, but I am not sure if I can use the dual of the Cech complex to calculate the homology of the manifold.

Comment: This should follow from the universal coefficient theorem and, I guess, the five lemma.

Comment: I tried to fit it into a cone, then I only need to show dual of acyclic complex is acyclic, then I think it is true since acyclic complex of finite free $\mathbb{Z}$ modules split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP pretty much gives a proof for the case of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules in comments:

$f:L\to M$ being a quasi-isomorphism is equivalent to the mapping cone $C_f$ of $f$ being acyclic. But an acyclic complex of free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules is contractible, and so applying any additive functor to it gives a contractible complex. In particular, the mapping cone of $M^\vee\to L^\vee$ (which is isomorphic to a shift of $C_f^\vee$) is contractible and therefore acyclic.

For $\mathbb{Z}/n$-modules it's also true, but for slightly different reasons. It's no longer true that an acyclic complex of free modules is contractible (although it is if the complex is bounded above or below), but $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is injective as a $\mathbb{Z}/n$-module, so the functor $M\mapsto M^\vee=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}/n}(M,\mathbb{Z}/n)$ is exact.